# labels showing up as doubles

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a problem in Qgis where all my labels are doubled on every single item (see image). I have checked the attributes list and everything seems normal. How do I show the labels properly?

[image: example]

Comment: What is your data source?

Comment: Check if you have added same layer twice with different label settings

Comment: A screenshot of your label style settings would be helpful here. Is the same field added to the style twice? Is the same layer with the same label style added twice?

Comment: You might have set an expression and accidentally added that field twice. But I agree with the above, a screenshot of your Label settings would be helpful.

Comment: I got the same problem any news here?